# Converting 'Enter' key event into a empty string or null in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keyboard, event-handling, keycode

How to convert 'Enter' key event into a space or empty string(' ') in react?

```
this.state = {
   ip: ''
};

inputChange = (e) => {  
      this.setState({ ip: e.target.value });   
};

render() {
   return(
      <>
       <textarea              
        onChange={this.inputChange}
        value={this.state.ip}
        placeholder='Enter here'
        ></textarea>
        <button>Enter</button>
      </>
   )
}
```

After entering values into the text area and now clicking on submit button, my output is like this :

**Hi↵I'm Human**

Required Output :

**Hi I'm Human**

**Edit**: If we click enter, it should go to next line in the textarea.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Regex and [.replace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) for the first part of your question.

**Edit**: The second part of your question it's not easy as I thought, and totally our logic doesn't work, so as you can see we should use `addEventListener` on `keyup`, then with information from the event we can add character into our input.

**Bonus**: I did use ref for focusing inside Textarea after clicking the `Enter` button for the better user's experience!

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
     ip: ''
  };
  inputRef = React.createRef()
  componentDidMount(){
     document.addEventListener("keyup", this.keyboardUp);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
      document.removeEventListener("keyup", this.keyboardUp);
  }
  keyboardUp = (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter' || e.keyCode === 13) {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(e.key)
        this.setState(prev => ({ ip: prev.ip + ' ' })); 
    }else{
        this.setState(prev => ({ ip: prev.ip + e.key })); 
    }
  }
  enterHandler = () => {
      this.setState(prev => ({ ip: prev.ip + '\n' })); 
      this.inputRef.current.focus();
  }
  render() {
     return(
         <div>
           <textarea
            ref={this.inputRef}
            placeholder='Enter here'
            value={this.state.ip}
            />
            <button onClick={this.enterHandler}>Enter</button>
         </div>
     )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: One more change required : If we click enter, it should go to next line in the textarea, is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it's easy too, ill update the example in a second.